# iOS/Swift programmatic equivalent of Android TableLayout/TableRow

Tags: android, ios, swift, tablelayout, tablerow

I am working on an iOS version of an Android application I wrote and I am having trouble figuring out the best way to display tabular data. Android has TableLayout and TableRow, making the task fairly simple.

The extra caveat is that however I create the data table, it needs to be created programmatically as there is an indeterminate # of tables to be displayed and each table has an indeterminate # of rows (all the information is pulled from a web service).

Also, if it helps, the app's orientation is portrait-only.

Here is an (ugly) example of how a table might look.

[image: Example Data Table]

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Would a TableView be the best direction here?

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell As far as I know, TableViews are not really meant for displaying tabular data.

Comment: Are the number of columns fixed or varied for each table?

Comment: @RichmondWatkins The number of columns is fixed for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom tableView Cell that has five labels.

```
class dynamicCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var col1 : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var col2 : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var col3 : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var col4 : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var col5 : UILabel

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Don't forget to link the outlets to the storyboard too.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am going to look more into this and give it a try.

Comment: This answer led me in the right direction, so I am picking it as the answer. More detail here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVJiprvRLoo

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` from iOS v6. UICollectionView is used for customization